# how to add scrollbars to ttk::combobox?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Is there a way to enable vertical and horizontal scrolling in ttk::combobox?

I looked at the https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_combobox.htm

this manual page doesn't have any option for scrollbars.

Regards,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vertical scrolling should automatically enable once you have sufficient values to choose between. There's no option to enable horizontal scrolling (and it isn't very good UX practice to have very long values in there); try keeping your individual values relatively short.